# Pointer to member question

Tags: c++, virtual, base-class, pointer-to-member

$4.11/2 states -

> An rvalue of type “pointer to member
>   of `B` of type *cv* `T`,” where `B` is a class
>   type, can be converted to an rvalue of
>   type “pointer to member of `D` of type
>   *cv* `T`,” where `D` is a derived class
>   (clause 10) of `B`. If `B` is an
>   inaccessible (clause 11), ambiguous
>   (10.2) or virtual (10.1) base class of
>   `D`, a program that necessitates this
>   conversion is ill-formed.

My question is why we have the restriction of `B` not being a virtual base class of `D`?

Answer (score 5):

Consider a situation involving a non-virtual base class:

```
class A { int a; }
class B : public A { int b; }
class C : public A { int c; }
class D : public B, public C { int d; }
```

Here's a possible memory layout:

```
+-------------+
| A: int a;   |
+-------------+
| B: int b;   |
+-------------+
| A: int a;   |
+-------------+
| C: int c;   |
+-------------+
| D: int d;   |
+-------------+
```

`D` ends up with two `A` subobjects because it inherits from `B` and `C` and both each have an `A` subobject.

Pointers to member variables are typically implemented as an integer offset from the start of the object. In this case, the integer offset for `int a` in an `A` object is zero. So a "pointer to `int a` of type `A`" may be simply an integer offset of zero.

To convert a "pointer to `int a` of type `A`" to a "pointer to `int a` of type `B`," you just need an integer offset to the `A` subobject located in `B` (the first `A` subobject).

To convert a "pointer to `int a` of type `A`" to a "pointer to `int a` of type `C`," you just need an integer offset to the `A` subobject located in `C` (the second `A` subobject).

Since the compiler knows where `B` and `C` is relative to `A`, the compiler has enough information on how to downcast from `A` to `B` or `C`.

Now consider a situation involving a virtual base class:

```
struct A { int a; }
struct B : virtual public A { int b; }
struct C : virtual public A { int c; }
struct D : public B, public C { int d; }
```

Possible memory layout:

```
+-------------+
| B: ptr to A | ---+
|    int b;   |    |
+-------------+    |
| C: ptr to A | ---+
|    int c;   |    |
+-------------+    |
| D: int d;   |    |
+-------------+    |
| A: int a;   | <--+
+-------------+
```

Virtual base classes are typically implemented by having `B` and `C` (which virtually derive from `A`) contain a pointer to the single `A` subjobject. The pointers to the `A` subobject are required because the location of `A` relative to `B` and `C` is not constant.

If all we had was a "pointer to `int a` of type `A`," we won't be able to cast it to a "pointer to `int a` of type `B`", since the location of the `B` and `C` subobjects can vary relative to `A`. `A` doesn't have back-pointers to `B` nor `C`, so we simply don't have enough information for the downcast to work.

Answer (score 1):

With non-virtual inheritance, the base-class and derived-class members can be laid out contiguously in memory, with the base class first, so that the each base-class member is at the same location relative to the object's address whether the object is a `B` or a `D`. This makes it easy to convert a pointer-to-member-of-`B` to a pointer-to-member-of-`D`; both can be represented as an offset from the object's address.

With virtual inheritance, base-class members must be accessed via a pointer (or equivalent) in the derived object, indicating where the base class is located. This would require adding extra information to the pointer-to-member representation to indicate that this indirection is needed, and would necessitate a run-time check when using *any* pointer-to-member.

A general principle behind much of C++ is to avoid run-time overhead wherever possible. In this case, the choice was between a run-time check on quite a common operation, versus disallowing quite an obscure conversion, and it seems that that principal was applied here.

Answer (score 0):

Really interesting question. Learned something new today. This is what I could find related to the subject: 
[Casting member function pointers from derived class to virtual base class does not work](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/6c8389eb-162a-4db2-95d3-87d6fe245836)